# Facebook's FacebookApiException class's error codes?

Tags: facebook

Where can I find a list of all the error codes for Facebook's FacebookApiException class? I found 2 such lists, both of which are outdated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/ and http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/faq/general/gen_10.html

From debugging my own script, I found out that error #2500 is "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." and error #3501 is "User is already associated to the article object on a unique action type Read." Neither error codes are in the links posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you. Most probably Login related error.
https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/issues/detail?id=453

Comment: That's only 1 error code. I want to know all the error codes to handle each error differently.

Comment: There is no such official/unofficial list of complete code errors available right now. There used to be, but FB has removed the list for some obvious reasons. This list might be helpful to some extent. Please check. https://github.com/phwd/fbec